# how to align center to page of which child div has some fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have as the following html...

```
<div>
    <h1>centered text</h1>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

and the css....

```
div{display: table; text-align: center; width: 100%;}
p{width: 100px;}
```

In the above code h1 is centered but not p. I have tried using margin-left: 50% to outer div and left: -50% to inner div but shows extra horizontal scroll-bar. So, I would like to use another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the style of `p` element:

```
p{width: 100px; margin: 0 auto}
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/enepuy/1/)

**Explain:**

The text of your `h1` is centered because the `h1` element inherits the `text-align` property from the `div` element and its width equals to the width of the `div` element.

Your `p` element inherits the center text align too, but it is just 100px length and have default position property, so **the whole** `p` element is sticked at the left side of the parent `div`. You have to set the left and right margin of the `p` element to make **the whole `p` element** centered inside the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

you only need this:

```
div{display: table; text-align: center; width: 100%; margin:0 auto}
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/xfGh2/

Comment: The only thing with this is that he may decide to have images, or other bits that he doesn't want centered. But if he does then go with this. +1'd.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 margin-left:auto;  
 margin-right:auto;
```

---

```
p  
{
 width: 100px;  
 margin-left:auto;  
 margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p{width:100px;margin:0 auto;}`
This sets a margin of 0 top and bottom, but centers it from left to right.

[Link to CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AIJHK)